# Python: Retrieve Tuples From Set Based on First Value of Tuple

Tags: python

Suppose I have a set, `s` that looks like this:

```
s = set([(1,2), (1,4), (2,6)])
```

I want to retrieve all tuples in my set that have first element `1`.  Usually I'd have to give a full tuple, something like:

```
(1,2) in s
```

In this case, I want to retrieve all tuples of the form `(1,_)` where `_` can be any number.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Edit: To be clear, I wanted to do this using a set because I want O(1) time.  I understand I could just iterate through a list and collect the tuples that have their first element as `1`, but am looking for something faster.

I thought of using a separate set for the first elements and a second set for the second elements but not sure how I'd use that to retrieve efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: use a dictionary where the key is the first element and the value is a list of values appearing as the second element

Comment: “I want to retrieve all tuples of the form (1, _) where _ can be any number”. You cannot do this in O(1). Finding a subset of a set where subset criteria can be fulfilled by anywhere from 0-N items is an O(N) operation.

Comment: You would need to store this differently. Storing it as a set and searching would take linear time.

Answer (score 4):

Using list comprehension.

```
s = set([(1,2), (1,4), (2,6)])
print(set([i for i in s if i[0] == 1]))    #Check if first value in tuple is 1
```

**Output:**

```
set([(1, 2), (1, 4)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `s = set([(1,2), (1,4), (2,6)])` use `d = {(1,):[(2,),(4,)], ((2,):[(6,)]}` Then you can generate list of tuples starting with 1 in worst case O(k) where k is max number of tuples starting with one particular value (which is hopefully much better than O(n)).

To do the lookup:

```
[(1,) + x for x in d[(1,)]]
```

Comment: It should be noted that creating d from s alone would take linear time.

Comment: although it would only have to be done once for the entire set

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension:

```
[t for t in s if t[0] == 1]
```

Result:

```
>>> s = set([(1,2), (1,4), (2,6)])
>>> [t for t in s if t[0] == 1]
[(1, 2), (1, 4)]
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer.  Meant is there a way to do it in constant time!  Otherwise, no need for the set at all, can just loop through a list of tuples.

Comment: What do you mean by constant time? You may edit your question, though.

Comment: As in the operation of retrieving these tuples takes O(1) time (yours takes linear time)

Answer (score 0):

Why not store your tuples in a `numpy` array?

```
import numpy as np

s = np.array([[1,2], [1,4], [2,6]])

s[np.where(s[:,0] == 1)]
```

gives you

```
array([[1,2], [1,4]])
```